# Is drawing outside the viewport in OpenGL expensive?

Tags: performance, opengl

I have several thousand quads to draw, some of which might fall entirely outside the viewport. I could write code which will detect which quads fall wholly outside viewport and ask OpenGL to draw only those which will be at least partially visible. Alternatively, I could simply have OpenGL draw all of the quads, regardless of whether they intersect with the viewport.

I don't have enough experience with OpenGL to know if one of these is obviously better (or if OpenGL offers some quick viewport intersection test I can use). Are draws outside the viewport close to being no-ops, or are they expensive enough that I should I try to avoid them?

Comment: "Several thousand" isn't very many by most standards. On modern hardware you might well be slower doing the culling yourself manually, but you should easily be able to get interactive framerates by just rendering everything. (It won't quite be a no-op, but it should be pretty cheap still)

Comment: I've drawn terrain with just over ~2 million triangles where most of the vertices were outside the viewport, still running >500fps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your circumstances.

Drawing is best done in batches, preferably batches that are static in structure (ie: each batch is drawn in its entirety). So you shouldn't be culling down at the quad level. But doing some culling of large groups of quads is not unwelcome.

The primary performance that you'll lose is vertex transform (aka: your vertex shader). A vertex shader has to be run on every vertex you provide, regardless of anything else. However, hardware will discard triangles that are trivially outside of the viewport, so you won't soak up any fillrate or other performance.

*However*, that doesn't mean that it's OK if your vertex T&L is cheap. Rendering large blocks of triangles that aren't visible may very well stall the rasterizer, because all of the triangles are being culled. That is, if you draw a lot of stuff that gets culled by being off screen, the fillrate that you might have used on actually visible triangles may be lost.

So it's not a good idea to just hurl geometry at the GPU willy-nilly.

In any case, if you're doing 2D rendering, coarse culling of discrete groups of quads is really all you need. You could divide your tilemap into screen-sized portions, and you draw up to 4 of these based on the position of the camera.

Comment: I am doing 2D rendering. With a few exceptions, each quad I'm drawing represents an object which gets moved around independently, so it's not clear to me how to batch drawing of them. (Though maybe I still can?) Your point about dividing the space into quarter-planes is well-taken. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I realize now that I misunderstood---you don't mean quarter planes, you mean viewport-sized chunks. That makes more sense than what I thought at first.